# design pattern for links

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a bunch of functors that take some data and build new ones when operator() is invoked.

```cpp
class Functor {
  void operator()() {
    pt = BaseFactory(INPUT);
  }
  std::shared_ptr<BASE> pt;
};
```

The input data of the functors may contain some "local" data to the functor, some "global static" data, or the result of another functor.

In the first two cases, the functor knows where data is. The problem comes with the last case, since functors may be deleted, modified and re-run, leading to reallocation or deletion of the actual data.

I was thinking of developing a single interface of a Link, that basically acts as a proxy for the data. Something like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Link {
  T & get();
};
```

Maybe, provide specializations for Persistent and Builded types and, in the last case, also provide methods to query the memory state of the data (broken link) or to ask who is supposed to build it.

How this kind of problems is generally approached?

Bonus question :
how to correctly define operator< to allow the use of associative containers, without risking to lose data? For example to have:

```cpp
class AnotherFunctor {
  void operator()() {
    for(auto & iter : map){
      iter.second = BaseFactory(iter.first.get());
    }
  }
  std::map<Link<INPUT>,std::shared_ptr<BASE>> map;
}
```

Comment: In this cases usually the functors can be arraged in a DAG structure, if you have cycles in dependecies they will never stop recalculating. If it is fitting with your case, you can have a DAG data structure that control the lifetime and the recalculation of the fuctors

Comment: if your functor dependends at most to another functors, the Direct Acyclic Graph is actually just a tree and you can model it with the composite pattern

Comment: I do already have a DAG in a separate structure which holds the Functors and know when to call them, detect cycles, etc. Here the problem is about data persistency. The functor operator() will do something like pt = make_shared<T>(...), so if I put "pt" in another functor as input parameter, I need to update everybody telling "now pt is this new one". Bookkeeping at the DAG-level does not seem to me the clearest way.

Comment: the observer pattern does what you want.